# Design of layered architecture for a Java application

Tags: java, architecture

I have code with the following architecture:

1. Business objects  (Represents business object [BO])
2. DataBasedModel classes (Maps to DB tables)

Layered Architecture

1. DAO (reads /write BO to DB, converts BO to DBModels and vice versa)
2. Each table has a DAO
3. I plan to have a manager layer on top of DAO.Manager will call DAOS.Manager handles business logic.And transactions

Consider that I have 3 tables: A,B,C

1. BOs: are A_BO ,B_BO ,C_BO
2. Managers: A_M,B_M,C_M
3. DAOs: A_DAO,B_DAO,C_DAO

All write operations of BO are handles by respective Manager (e.g. To write into A_BO, manager A is always called).

For some operations, I need to access multiple tables/BO.

For example to insert a record into A, I need to check something into table B. Write of A is handled by A managed.

Can manager A call B_DAO? or should it only call B_Manager? and not access B_DAO?

Some concerns:

If manager calls some other manager I cannot put an @Transaction Annotation on manager and I will need one more layers on top of the Manager then.

Comment: You can put `@Transaction` on a manager method even if it calls another manager's `@Transaction`al methods. The second method will participate in the first method's transaction.

Comment: That will result in nested transaction right and fail with exception

Comment: @Is my question too dumb?noone is answering :(.I would like to know opionions from you guys  as am in delema

Comment: It will not result in nested transaction unless you explicitly use nested propagation mode. Also, nested transactions don't always fail, they wouldn't be there if they always failed.

Comment: How do i prevent it from using the same transaction if its alredy existing?Using propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED??

Comment: Yes. That's how you do it.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. Can you also give ur thoughts on My main question too?About which design will be more clear?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51937/discussion-between-abhinav-sarkar-and-user93796)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the differences of your DAO layer and manager layer. They seem to have the same responsibility: manage entities.

On the other hand I miss something like a business layer. Inside a business logic you will have usecases which need access to more than one entity. For example to store a new bill you will have updates on billing data, customer accounts, maybe warehouse stock and lots of other entities. All these updates should occur inside one transaction. Therefore you should see all functionylity defined in your current DAO and manager layer as one persistence layer, that's functionality can only be used inside of transactions. To have one DAO per entity is a common pattern here.

Transactions should be triggered by some business layer where the supplied functionality does something usefull in terms of your application logic. That's also the point where transaction demarcation and other aspects like permission checking can be implemented.

Comment: @Blafasel.Yes .But can i call dao of B from manger of A? IF A manager want to chekc something in B?

Comment: @user93796 Of course. You should avoid calls from manager to manager to avoid problems in transaction demarcation. Factoring out common used functionality into some commons or utitlity classes that are not part of the public interface is a common pattern here.

Comment: @Abhinav : any comments?

Comment: can plz u join us at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51937/discussion-between-abhinav-sarkar-and-user93796